# Angular 11 how to display text with new lines like <p> defined in component

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 11. I want to display text message in template which is defined in component. Want the text message to be displayed in individual lines. i.e i am trying following but not working.

in component:

```
public warningMessage = `You have not created any learners yet!`+ '\n' + `Your can start either by 
    importing your learners from a previous system or creating new ones directly from here.`;
```

in html:

```
<div>{{warningMessage}}</div>
```

But the line is not displaying in individual line.

Thanks

Comment: try this in css: `white-space: pre-line;`

Answer (score 0):

You can display it with an array

in your html

```
<p *ngFor="let message of messages"> {{message}} </p>
```

in your component

```
warningMessage = ['You have not created any learners yet!','Your can start either by 
importing your learners from a previous system or creating new ones directly from here.']
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you are using is called Text interpolation which allows to add  dynamic string values into your HTML templates. This will thus print everything as text. A solution to this is

In Ts File =>

```
public warningMessage = `You have not created any learners yet! <br/> Your can start either by 
    importing your learners from a previous system or creating new ones directly from here.`;
```

In Html File =>

```
<div [innerHTML]="warningMessage"></div>
```